# VS Code 2017 stops working after sometime

Tags: visual-studio-code

I left VSCode open last night and when I returned the editor was frozen already and wouldn't quit even through mac's Force Quit utility. It finally did quit and the process doesn't show up on the task manager anymore. Its icon on the dock has also gone missing.

However, when I check on the terminal I still see the following process:

```
$ ps -aef | grep code
  501 29728 29691   0 11:51AM ??         0:01.58 /private/var/folders/l_/xgbzwc3j0xn_cb74550m71vr0000gn/T/AppTranslocation/C84B50E8-6738-4546-85BA-35B7EA23C58C/d/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Frameworks/Code Helper.app/Contents/MacOS/Code Helper /private/var/folders/l_/xgbzwc3j0xn_cb74550m71vr0000gn/T/AppTranslocation/C84B50E8-6738-4546-85BA-35B7EA23C58C/d/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/extensions/typescript/out/utils/electronForkStart.js /private/var/folders/l_/xgbzwc3j0xn_cb74550m71vr0000gn/T/AppTranslocation/C84B50E8-6738-4546-85BA-35B7EA23C58C/d/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/extensions/node_modules/typescript/lib/tsserver.js --useInferredProjectPerProjectRoot --enableTelemetry --cancellationPipeName /var/folders/l_/xgbzwc3j0xn_cb74550m71vr0000gn/T/vscode-tscancellation-66bfa8d8041349b73f73.sock* --locale en
```

`kill -9 ${ps -aef | grep code}` doesn't kill it.

What should I do now?

Unable to uninstall, reinstall or remove the IDE off my macbook pro 2017.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reboot without reopening applications is the only way out.